# Run cURL command using Process builder

Tags: java, curl, processbuilder

I want to put the following cURL command in the Process Builder:

```
curl --negotiate -u : -b ~/cookiejar.txt -c ~/cookiejar.txt http://********.com
```

cookiejar.txt is a Netscape HTTP Cookie File.

Comment: why do you want this when you can make the http request right from java ?

Comment: What's the problem....?

Comment: I don't know how to send the credentials from the cookiejar.txt.

Comment: What have you tried? What happens when you do it?

Comment: "I don't know how to send the credentials ..." now that's the question :) hmmm I know about apache httpclient library but I don't know how to deal with cookies sorry

Comment: anyway even if curl turned out to be absolutely necessary I'd use libcurl instead (sorry the java bindings are old you might have to use JNI/JNA for that)

Comment: It works with curl command but with Process Builder, the problem is **how to add the cookiejar.txt as arguments**.

Answer (score 2):

My doubt was how to put the above curl command in the Process Builder. 
I figured it out. :)

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl", "--negotiate", "-u" ,":" ,"-b", "~/cookiejar.txt", "-c", "~/cookiejar.txt", "http://********.com");
Process p = pb.start();

InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

String line = new String();

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("read line from curl command: " + line);
    responseStrBuilder.append(line);
}
```

The above code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
     "curl", "--negotiate", "-u", ":", 
     "-b", "~/cookiejar.txt", "-c", "~/cookiejar.txt", 
     "http://********.com");
 pb.redirectErrorStream(true); 
 // other stuff you choose to do to pb -- see ProcessBuilder JavaDoc
 Process p = pb.start();
 try(InputStream response = p.getInputStream()) {
     // read response
 }
```

`redirectErrorStream` prevents problems where you're trying to read from cUrl's stdout, while cUrl is writing an error to stderr. There are smarter but more complex ways to do this that keep stderr and stdout apart, but I leave those as an exercise for the reader.

---

**However** -- shelling out to an external command is bad practice, and should be reserved for when you really, really need it. It's bad practice because it causes problems -- problems you'll be glad to avoid. So I recommend using a native Java HTTP client. Apache Commons HttpClient is reliable, and has all the Cookie-handling abilities you could need.